# Connect Cloud Kafka server from local system

Tags: apache-kafka

I have Installed  kafka in Cloud server 
I wish to connect cloud-kafka server from my local system

My cloud kafka server Internal IP :

```
10.340.0.90
```

My cloud kafka server Public IP :

```
aa.xx.yy.zz
```

My local system IP :

```
172.168.1.100
```

File name: `config/server.properties`

uncommented and changed the below line:

```
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
to
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.340.0.90:9092
```

Restarted the Kafka , zookeeper

Inspite of the above , i'm not able to connect remote kafka server from my local network

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem. where you able to connect from you local system to cloud. if yes please let me know as i also have a similar issue.waiting for a positive reply.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the config/server.properties:

```
listeners=INTERNAL://10.340.0.90:9092, EXTERNAL://aa.xx.yy.zz:9093
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

And configure bootstrap servers in your source code:

```
Producer:
Map props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, aa.xx.yy.zz:9093);
```

```
Consumer:
Map props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, aa.xx.yy.zz:9093);
```

Comment: yes, it could listen in same port but better be different because the INTERNAL endpoint is used to communicate between nodes in a cluster and EXTERNAL endpoint is used by your Kafka client to connect to Kafka brokers. I forgot to ask if your Kafka cluster is single broker or multi-brokers cluster. If it is a single broker cluster then you don't need to configure INTERNAL endpoint.

Comment: Added as below in kafka server properities and restarted the kafka. but still the same isue retains `listeners= EXTERNAL://aa.xx.yy.zz:9092`
`listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092`

Comment: Do you have duplicated listeners setting ? Can you only try with listeners= EXTERNAL://aa.xx.yy.zz:9092. If your Kafka server is protected by SSL then try to add listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:SSL

Comment: Added `listeners= EXTERNAL://aa.xx.yy.zz:9092` alone in the server properities file. restarted kafka. kafka logs shows as : `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No security protocol defined for listener PLAINTEXT`

Comment: kafka server was not under ssl (not domain based)

Comment: tried  `listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:EXTERNAL`  in the config file for the above error. restarted the kafka . it shows the below error`FATAL  (kafka.Kafka$)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid security protocol `EXTERNAL` defined in listener.security.protocol.map`

Comment: tried `listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:SSL` in the server properties restarted the kafka. it shows the below error  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: inter.broker.listener.name must be a listener name defined in advertised.listeners. The valid options based on currently configured listeners are EXTERNAL`

Comment: kafka server is only public ip based. it has no domain

Comment: ok, now can you try listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT

Comment: Tried it .`listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT`  it reports the below on restarting: `FATAL  (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: inter.broker.listener.name must be a listener name defined in advertised.listeners. The valid options based on currently configured listeners are EXTERNAL`

Comment: you comment inter.broker.listener.name as this parameter is used for communication between brokers. You has only one broker so no need to set it.

Comment: `inter.broker.listener.name` there is no such line my server properities

Comment: what is your current configuration of listener and advertised.listeners in server.properties now ? Can you share as much as possible your server.properties file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171781/discussion-between-soundararajan-c-and-quang-vien).